# function returns "undefined" in react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

My Function in a class returns undefined when trying to use the return value.

**App.js:**

```
let db = new Database()
let username = db.get()

return(
  //returns undefined
  <p>{username}</p>
)
```

**database.js:**

```
class Database {
 [...]

 get(){
 [...]
 .then((result) => {
    //console.log logs the right data
    console.log(result.rows[0])
    return (result.rows[0])
  })
 }
}
```

Comment: Probably database.js returns nothing, because ```return``` in ```then()``` doesn't return from ```get()```. Could you show the whole database.js?

Comment: Are you importing `Database` from `database.js`? Is the class `Database` being exported correctly from `database.js`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expect get() in Database to return a result, you need to return the resolved result from the promise. Otherwise, it is just a void method.

```
class Database {
 [...]

 async get(){
 return await [...]
     .then((result) => {
        //console.log logs the right data
        console.log(result.rows[0])
        return (result.rows[0])
      })
   }
}
```

Note that in this case [...] must be the promise object. By marking the method as async and then waiting for the promise result you are able to return the resolved value instead of undefined.